# std::experimental::ostream_joiner and std::pair

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17

In c++17/g++7, there's finally the long missed ostream_joiner. It enables proper output to ostreams, separating collection elements with infix delimiters.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using string = std::string;
#if 1
struct pair {
    string first;
    string second;
};
#else
using pair = std::pair<string,string>;
#endif


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const pair &p) {
    return lhs << p.first << "=" << p.second;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<pair> pairs = {{"foo", "bar"}, {"baz", "42"}};
    std::copy(std::begin(pairs),
          std::end(pairs),
          std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ", "));
}
```

Whilst the code piece succesfully compiles and outputs ...

```
foo=bar, baz=42
```

... changing the #if 1 to a #if 0 in the snippet makes the compiler complaining about missing the proper shift operator:

```
main.cpp:29:70:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/7.2.0/experimental/iterator:88:10: error: no match for 
'operator<<' (operand types are 
'std::experimental::fundamentals_v2::ostream_joiner<const char*, char, 
std::char_traits<char> >::ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 
'const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >')
  *_M_out << __value;
```

Does somebody have a clue why?

## update

Barry has given the right answer to the question. It however does not solve the problem, and running a manual loop is not in the sense of reusing existing stl code, so the question gets extended to:

Is it possible to make the stream operator work without polluting the std namespace?

Comment: this [could be a soultion](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h2NGXRT88q18q8m5), but I don't like it, since it touches `std` name space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere inside of the implementation of `ostream_joiner`, there will be an attempt to something like:

```
os << value;
```

where `os` is a `std::basic_ostream` and value is your `pair` type. In order to determine what to do for that `operator<<` call, we lookup all the overloads `operator<<()` visible at the point of definition of this template as well as as the overloads in the *associated namespaces* of the arguments (this is known as [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)).

When you use *your* `struct pair`, the associated namespace of `pair` is `::`, so ADL will find your `::operator<<(std::ostream&, pair const&)`. This overload works, is chosen, everything is happy.

When you use `std::pair`, the associated namespace of `pair` is `std` and there is no `operator<<()` that can be found that takes a `std::pair`. Hence the error.

---

You could instead create your own type in your own namespace for which you can add an overloaded `operator<<`, this can be fully your own type (the way it is in the question) or you could inherit the one in `std`:

```
struct pair : std::pair<string,string> {
    using std::pair<string,string>::pair;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, my_pair const& ) {...}
```

Alternatively, you could just not use `make_ostream_joiner`. Could replace this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(pairs),
      std::end(pairs),
      std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ", "));
```

with this:

```
const char* delim = "";
for (auto const& pair : pairs) {
    std::cout << delim << pair; // now, our point of definition does include
                                // our operator<<() declaration, we don't need ADL
    delim = ", ";
}
```

Comment: thanks, stupid me - accepted. However: do we need to pollute the namespace by inserting the stream operator into it, or give up here?

Comment: @argonaut6x Adding new functions into namespace std is UB, so don't do that.

Comment: so we're giving up? No alternatives to make operator << with std::pair working?

Comment: @argonaut6x Don't use `std::pair`? Use a for loop instead of `copy` and `make_ostream_joiner`?

Comment: well, I was asking for the reason why this did not work, and got a proper answer to that question. However, the suggestion to not use std::pair and / or running a loop instead of reusing stl code is counterproductive, imo.

Comment: but it works for me under [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QuippPuOcgKe6k9g) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5Pc0hvAojfSrzxwm).

Comment: @MarekR Change your `#if 1` to `#if 0`

Comment: @argonaut6x Those are the two options. Not sure why you consider that "counterproductive."

Comment: @Barry I've missed that, sorry. Anyway this [could be a soultion](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h2NGXRT88q18q8m5), but I don't like it, since it touches `std` name space.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make the stream operator work without polluting the std namespace?

If you're willing to replace your `copy` with a `transform`, then yes - with `put_invocation` taken from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56511236/102441), you can use:

```
std::transform(
    std::begin(pairs), std::end(pairs),
    std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ", "),
    [](auto& p) {
        return put_invocation([&p = p](auto& os) {
            // adl works just fine here
            return os << p;
            // or `os << p.first << "=" << p.second;`
        });
    }
);
```

This should optimize to exactly the same code as the version that injects into the std namespace.